# Unable to scroll down the calendar while automate the Yatra.com (Selenium webdriver using python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I tried to automate the Yatra website but got stuck while selecting the values in the calendar. I am not able to scroll down the calendar.

[Website](https://www.yatra.com/)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYQGO.jpg)

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , write required information so that people can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this in python:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your xpath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to locate some element by scrolling down, the following code will scroll until the element is in view.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='PegasusCal-0']//div[@class='cal-body']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
Thread.sleep(500); 

//do anything you want with the element
```

Comment: Be more respectful when demanding code from others @SaniketA.Soni